# Issues with Throttle Control on ESC with RPi 3B+

Tags: python-3, pwm, pigpio, dc-motor

I am using the 30A BLDC ESC to control a brushless motor from my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. The documentation for the ESC can be found here: [ESC pdf](https://www.optimusdigital.ro/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=451)

I seem to have successfully calibrated the ESC, but after it is finished arming, it emits a 56712 tone and, indicating the direction of throttle is reversed -- I'm not quite sure what this means and how to fix. I have the right battery for the ESC (11.1V Li-Po battery).

I do not have an additional hat or board for my Raspberry Pi... Should I invest in one? Could this provide throttle control that the Pi is unable to for some reason?

The code I wrote is below (Python 3.8):

```
# libraries
import os
import sys

# Linux path
sys.path.append('./subsystems')

# RPi path
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/reyna/Airplane/subsystems')

# subsystems
from motor_pigpio import Motor_Pigpio

class Configure():

    def __init__(self):
        ### INSTANTIATE ###
        self.cockpit = Motor_Pigpio()

        ### CALIBRATE ###
        self.cockpit.calibrate(18)

config = Configure()
```

```
# libraries
import pigpio
import time

class Motor_Pigpio():

    ### define ###

    # duty cycle
    # frequency

    def __init__(self):
        self.pi = pigpio.pi()
        print(self.pi.connected)
        # successfully prints 'True'

    def max_val(self, pin_num):
        self.pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin_num, 2000)

    def min_val(self, pin_num):
        self.pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin_num, 700)

    def calibrate(self, pin_num):
        self.pi.set_mode(pin_num, 1)
        self.pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin_num, 0)
        time.sleep(1)
        inpt = input()
        if inpt == '':
            self.max_val(pin_num)
            print("Connect BATTERY now. Wait for 2 beeps. Enter.")
            inpt = input()
            time.sleep(1)
            if inpt == '':
                self.min_val(pin_num)
                print("Special tone")
                time.sleep(7)
                print("Just wait...")
                time. sleep(5)
                self.pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin_num, 0)
                time.sleep(2)
                print("ARMING")
                time.sleep(1)

    def arm(self, pin_num):
        # minimum throttle
        self.min_val(pin_num)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.max_val(pin_num)
        time.sleep(1)

    def run(self, pin_num, freq, throttle):
#        self.pi.set_PWM_range(pin_num, 255)
        self.pi.set_PWM_frequency(pin_num, freq)
#        self.pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(pin_num, dc)
        self.pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(pin_num, throttle)

    def end_run(self):
        #self.pi.stop()
        pass
```

I apologize in advance if another thread already exists for this. I have been searching for a few hours to no avail.

Edit: I have tested the code on a servo. Noticed that the servo goes almost to its extrema but not all the way. Is this to be expected or is something off?

Comment: your links seems broken!

Comment: whoops, you're right! I changed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial problem seems to be irrelevant. I did not understand what was meant by "throttle" which is more of an RC jargon misunderstanding than it is an issue with raspberry pi. (If you're looking for an answer [this link](https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/esc-calibration.html) shows it pretty well.)

Sorry for being off-topic! Sometimes it's hard to know when you are working from little experience. :)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.